# How to sum in SQL with conditions?

Tags: sql, ms-access

It's more than likely this question has already been asked before and that I could just not find it now knowing for what to search.

Assuming I have a simple table with two columns, one column holding one of two values, e.g. "positive" and "negative", and the other holding an integer.

Is there a way using standard SQL to calculate a sum of all the numbers in the second column whereby the number is added if the field in the first column reads "positive" and vice-versa subtracted for "negative" numbers?

Also, it would be interesting to understand how to do the same with MS Access if it is different from standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You case use `sum(case)`:

```
select sum(case when col1 = '+' then value
                when col2 = '-' then - value
           end) as overall
from t;
```

In MS Access, you would use `switch` or `iff`

```
select sum(switch(col1 = '+', value, col2 = '-', - value, 0)
          ) as overall
from t;
```

Comment: @vic . . . You should tag your questions appropriately.